# EXTRA_PEER_ID undefined when developing android wear watchface using the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, wear-os

I'm trying to develop an Android wear watchface using a physical handheld device (for the companion app) and the emulator as watch.

It seems that I can connect my physical device to the emulator watch just fine using [Google's instructions](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html), the emulator shows as connected in the Android Wear app.

My problem is that I can't get the EXTRA_PEER_ID of the emulator from the companion app, like in the example (line 67) from the [WatchFace example](https://developer.android.com/samples/WatchFace/Application/src/com.example.android.wearable.watchface/DigitalWatchFaceCompanionConfigActivity.html):

```
    mPeerId = getIntent().getStringExtra(WatchFaceCompanion.EXTRA_PEER_ID);
```

The WatchFaceCompanion.EXTRA_PEER_ID is undefined in the setup with the emulator.

It's working perfectly fine if I try the code with a physical handheld and a physical watch, it's only undefined if I use the emulator as the watch.

Any idea on how to get the Peer ID with the emulator, since the ID is needed when trying to send a message from the companion activity to the watch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same issue. I was building a companion activity for my settings and I used the activity as a standalone activity. After I invoked the activity via the Android Wear app was the peerId present.

Comment: Yep, that was it! Thanks.